# Windows forms iniciar com sistema operacional

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, instalador

Como faço para que o usuário tenha a opção de escolher se o sistema (system tray c#) irá iniciar com o SO ou não através da instalação no WizardSetup (Visual Studio 2010)?

Comment: O que seria este WizardSetup? Algum produto de instalação? Ou você está falando do Setup Wizard presente no VS?

Comment: seria o setup wizard presente no VS

Comment: Você deseja saber se o WizardSetup tem uma opção que permite instalar e colocar o aplicativo para iniciar sempre com o Windows (na pasta Inicializar, shell:startup)?

Comment: tipo o skype, quando é feita a instalação do skype ele pergunta se você deseja que o skype inicie ao inicializar o sistema operacional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existe o **Registry editor** onde permite voce registrar chaves.
Oque voce precisa fazer é adicionar uma chave de inicialização nela no seguinte caminho: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Porem o Value a incluir nele devera ser o caminho da sua aplicação, não tenho certeza...

Tem um link muito explicativo de como utilizar:

**[setup-and-deployment-in-visual-studio-2010](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/231074-setup-and-deployment-in-visual-studio-2010/)**
 *Procure pela parte do Registry editor no link;*

---

Voce pode fazer via codigo tambem **dentro da sua aplicação**:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
key.SetValue("Your Application Name", @"Your application path.exe");
```

---

Existe o **InstallShield** quee não é da microsoft porem é um dos melhores que existe... . No visual studio voce tem de graça a versão limitada, onde não suporta opções avançadas como essa que voce esta requerindo

[Link WizardSetup](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/producer/products/software-installation/installshield-software-installer/).

Answer (score 5):

Boa noite complementando a resposta acima, Existe esse método que eu utilizo em C# com ele você pode colocar para sua aplicação iniciar com o Windows ou até mesmo removê-la.. como isso voce pode por aquela configuração na aplicação para inicar com o Windows.. o método é esse:

```
public static void SetStartup(bool OnOff)
    {
    try{
    //Nome a ser exibido no registro ou quando Der MSCONFIG - Pode Alterar
        string appName = "SAT Manager - 4Way Systems";

        //Diretorio da chave do Registro NAO ALTERAR
        string runKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run";

        //Abre o registro
        RegistryKey startupKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

        //Valida se vai incluir o iniciar com o Windows ou remover
        if (OnOff)//Iniciar
        {
            if (startupKey.GetValue(appName) == null)
            {
                // Add startup reg key
                startupKey.SetValue(appName, @""""+ Application.ExecutablePath.ToString()  +@"""");
                startupKey.Close();
            }
        }
        else//Nao iniciar mais
        {
            // remove startup
            startupKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(runKey, true);
            startupKey.DeleteValue(appName, false);
            startupKey.Close();
        }
        }catch(Exception ex){
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Em alguns casos a aplicação tem que ser executada Como Administrador para ter acesso ao registro.